# suggest add favicon.ico to api endpoints

Tags: support

It will reduce 404 entries in your logs and in our browser based fiddler results.

Cheap, easy, fast.

```
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Host: api.stackoverflow.com
Connection: Keep-Alive


HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 12 Aug 2010 14:30:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip

fc
?
```

Comment: Hmmm... that's seems like a good reason. +1